# Application is incompatible with tablets

Tags: android, xamarin, publish, tablet

I have a project created in Xamarin Studio that seems to have some problems when I publish in Google Play:

When the application is published, I can install in phones normally, but when I try to access the application in Google Play through a tablet it says the application is incompatible with the device.

I'm new to android development, so I have some questions about this... I tried to had the compatible screens in the application manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="my.package.name" android:versionName="1.0.0" android:versionCode="42">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <permission android:protectionLevel="signature" android:name="my.package.name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="my.package.name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <application android:label="MyApplication" android:icon="@drawable/Icon" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/FacebookAppID" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:label="@string/ApplicationName" />
    <service android:name="parse.ParsePushService" />
    <receiver android:name="parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="my.package.name" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    </application>
    <compatible-screens>
        <!--all normal size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <!-- all large size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <!-- all xlarge size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <!-- Special case for Nexus 7 -->
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="213" />
     </compatible-screens>
</manifest>
```

I received some email's that the tablets weren't compatible, so I tried 1 physical tablet and 2 virtual tablets and they really weren't compatible.

Do I need to had something else? Or the problem is in Google Play Developer Console?

Comment: You shouldn't need the compatible-screens tag in the manifest. Can you post the rest of your manifest? You should be able to check the device list in your APK detail page in the Google Play Dev Console to see if any tablets are listed there. Are you sure that all tablets are incompatible or is it just a specific tablet type? I also added the following to my manifest but don't think it would prevent tablets `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait" android:required="false" />` & `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.landscape" android:required="false" />`

Comment: I updated the question with the entire manifest. So, I should try and add the code that you provided?

Comment: Yea try that code but I do not think that would prevent anything without it. I do not have any `compatible-screen` tags in my manifest at all and it works fine on tablets so I would keep that out of your manifest. I would also look in the Google Play Dev Console on the 'APK' Tab and make sure there is 0 in the 'Excluded devices' box and maybe also look in the 'Supported Devices' to see if any tablets are in there. *Edit: Also are you uploading a single APK or multiple?

Comment: I'm uploading a single APK. I'll give a try with your code. I will comment this as soon has I have some results. Thanks!

Comment: I followed your advice to check the Excluded Devices, and there is none excluded devices, however when I check the supported devices and search for the keyword "tablet" it only shows about 20 tablets.

Comment: Thats weird I have about 80 listed. Hopefully someone else has run into this before! Sorry I couldn't be more helpful. *Edit: Final thought would be which architectures do you have checked?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what your are asking: I checked armeabi-v7a. Should I check all of them?

Comment: Not necessarily, but you should at least check `armeabi`, `armeabi-v7a`, and `x86`. You could do the other two but we do not since we use LLVM compiling in release mode, which is not compatible with the 64 bit architectures. The good thing about that is that all of the 64 bit architectures can still use 32 bit builds so they all still get covered if you check those 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just going to post everything I said as an answer. The order I put these in does not correlate with importance.

You should not need to use the `<compatible-screens>` unless your app should only run on certain screens.

In my manifest, I have added the following, though this may not be required for you:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.landscape" android:required="false" />
```

I would look in the Google Dev Console and make sure you are not excluding devices and maybe look to see if any Tablets are in the supported devices list. I have 80 if I search 'Tablet'.

Finally, make sure you are at least checking the following architectures: `armeabi-v7a` and `x86`. `armeabi` is deprecated and you could do the other two but we do not since we use LLVM compiling in release mode, which is not compatible with the 64 bit architectures. The good thing about that is that all of the 64 bit architectures can still use 32 bit builds so they all still get covered if you check those 3.

Comment: I accepted the answer, because using the node <uses-feature> that you provided in the comments, plus checking the architectures that you mentioned, solved my problem for now.. I also removed the <compatible-screens> node.. thank you for the help!

Comment: Glad it helped! I added the `<uses-feature>` tag to my answer also.